# Subquery returned more than 1 value.

Tags: sql, sql-server

Once I run this query I get the following error

```
UPDATE stockloan_feed 
SET CUSIP =( 
      SELECT CUSIP FROM stockloan_feed_cusip_matching 
      WHERE stockloan_feed_cusip_matching.SEDOL = stockloan_feed.SEDOL OR       
      stockloan_feed_cusip_matching.ISIN = stockloan_feed.ISIN) 
WHERE CUSIP IS NULL and date = DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()-1)
```

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: do you have different `CUSIP`s in your subquery?

Comment: Try reading the error message. What do you want to do about it? You have multiple (possibly different!) values, and only one can be set... You didn't "tell" the DB which one you want from them

Comment: Are (SEDOL, ISIN) pairs unique per row on `stockloan_feed_cusip_matching` table? I think you have duplicates in these values which is the reason you get more than one row from the subquery. I would write some queries to find out whether there are duplicates in `stockloan_feed_cusip_matching ` table.

Comment: Run this query, and if it returns anything then you have duplicate values select * 
from stockloan_feed_cusip_matching a 
where exists(select 1 
             from stockloan_feed_cusip_matching b 
             where (a.SEDOL = b.SEDOL 
                or a.ISIN = b.ISIN)
             and a.CUSIP <> b.CUSIP)
and exists (select 1 from stockloan_feed c where a.SEDOL = c.SEDOL or a.ISIN = c.ISIN)

Comment: You may need to add unique constraints on both `SEDOL` and `ISIN` together in `stockloan_feed_cusip_matching` table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.CUSIP = t2.CUSIP
FROM  stockloan_feed t1
INNER JOIN stockloan_feed_cusip_matching t2 
        ON t2.SEDOL = t1.SEDOL 
        OR t2.ISIN  = t1.ISIN
WHERE t1.CUSIP IS NULL
  AND t1.date = DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()-1)
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud! This worked. Unfortunately this query takes almost 6 minutes to run as there are about 2 million rows in cusip_matching and about 20000 rows in stockloan_feed. Do you know if there si any way i can run this query in less time?

Comment: @user1753675 - This is fastest way, as far as I know. Try to add indexes in `ISIN` and `SEDOL` in the two tables. Or, you can start a new question on this subject. But, please try to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, you're trying to assign a column value to the result of a sub-query, but the sub-query is returning more than one value.

You could try specifying you only want the first result from the sub-query:

```
UPDATE stockloan_feed
SET    CUSIP = (SELECT TOP 1 CUSIP
                FROM   stockloan_feed_cusip_matching
                WHERE  stockloan_feed_cusip_matching.SEDOL = stockloan_feed.SEDOL
                        OR stockloan_feed_cusip_matching.ISIN = stockloan_feed.ISIN)
WHERE  CUSIP IS NULL
       AND date = Datediff(d, 0, Getdate() - 1)
```

This does of course assume that all possible values returned by your sub-query are the same, or you just don't mind which one of the matching results is assigned to your `stockloan_feed.CUSIP` column.