# SQL ERROR: This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I got this error in SQL Server 2012:

```
 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , > , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

This is my script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Update_F_ARTCLIENT

@PK varchar(19)
,@AR_Ref varchar(19)
,@AC_Categorie smallint
,@AC_PrixVen numeric(24,6)
,@AC_Coef numeric(24,6)
,@AC_PrixTTC smallint
,@AC_Remise numeric(24,6)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE [dbo].[F_ARTCLIENT]

SET

[AR_Ref] = @AR_Ref
,[AC_Categorie] = @AC_Categorie 
,[AC_PrixVen] = @AC_PrixVen
,[AC_Coef]= @AC_Coef
,[AC_PrixTTC] = @AC_PrixTTC
,[AC_Remise] = @AC_Remise

WHERE (SELECT CONCAT([AR_Ref], [AC_Categorie]) as PK FROM [dbo].[F_ARTCLIENT])= @PK

END
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your WHERE condition to be:

```
WHERE CONCAT([AR_Ref], [AC_Categorie]) = @PK
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error description reports, your subquery return more than a value. You can avoid this changing your subquery in this way:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT([AR_Ref], [AC_Categorie]) as PK FROM [dbo].[F_ARTCLIENT])= @PK)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly in the `where` clause.  Presumably, you want to do the update where this condition is true.  One pay is to change the logic to an `in`:

```
WHERE @pk in (SELECT CONCAT([AR_Ref], [AC_Categorie]) as PK FROM [dbo].[F_ARTCLIENT])
```

However, I notice that the table in the subquery is the same as the data being updated.  Do you really just mean this:

```
WHERE @pk = CONCAT([AR_Ref], [AC_Categorie])
```

That is, I don't think the subquery is necessary.