# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sm.Prnataccuserdivisionmappinglist @ENTITYCODE INT, 
                                                    @USERCODE   INT 
WITH encryption 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT D.flddivisioncode, 
             D.flddivisionname, 
             M.fldcompanydivisionno, 
             (SELECT flddivisioncode 
              FROM   sm.tblnataccuserdivisionmap 
              WHERE  flddivisioncode = D.flddivisioncode 
                     AND fldentitycode = @ENTITYCODE 
                     AND fldusercode = @USERCODE)AS FLDMAPSTATUS 
      FROM   sm.tbldivisiondetails D 
             INNER JOIN sm.tblnataccdivisionmapping M 
                     ON M.flddivisioncode = D.flddivisioncode 
                        AND fldcompanyentitycode = @ENTITYCODE 
  END
```

Comment: The answer is in the question - read what the error is telling you - that subquery `(SELECT flddivisioncode ...)` should only return one value - but your code returns more than one.

Comment: Brutally easy to find on https://www.google.com/search?q=Subquery+returned+more+than+1+value.+This+is+not+permitted+when+the+subquery+follow, and a duplicate of so many questions it's not even funny.

Comment: As an aside, the with encryption does NOT prevent somebody from viewing your code. Even worse is that it makes it really difficult to work with. You have to be extremely diligent with source control and it is very challenging to know which version is actually running on a given instance. Why bother encrypting a procedure like this anyway? If you don't put business rules in your procedures there is nothing to protect in the first place.

Comment: Sorry I am new in programming , i do not know more about SQL and programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Answer (score 1):

As you say yourself, the subquery is returning multiple values. I imagine you actually want to retrieve different rows for each value. I think this might be a new approach:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sm.Prnataccuserdivisionmappinglist @ENTITYCODE INT, @USERCODE INT 
WITH encryption 
AS 
  BEGIN 
  SELECT D.flddivisioncode, 
         D.flddivisionname, 
         M.fldcompanydivisionno, 
         M2.flddivisioncode AS FLDMAPSTATUS 
  FROM   sm.tbldivisiondetails D 
         INNER JOIN sm.tblnataccdivisionmapping M  ON M.flddivisioncode = D.flddivisioncode AND fldcompanyentitycode = @ENTITYCODE 
         INNER JOIN sm.tblnataccuserdivisionmap M2  ON M2.flddivisioncode = D.flddivisioncode
  WHERE M2.fldentitycode = @ENTITYCODE AND M2.fldusercode = @USERCODE
  END
```

The problem was that the multiple values were in the select statement; which is not correct since you would have mutiple values in a single cell.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Prnataccuserdivisionmappinglist, Line 12
Invalid column name 'fldentitycode'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Prnataccuserdivisionmappinglist, Line 12
Invalid column name 'fldusercode'.,Its showing error 'fldentitycode' and 'fldusercode' is invalid.

Comment: yep: The table name from the second join was wrong. I corrected it. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of aggregate function on your subquery.

```
(SELECT flddivisioncode 
              FROM   sm.tblnataccuserdivisionmap 
              WHERE  flddivisioncode = D.flddivisioncode 
                     AND fldentitycode = @ENTITYCODE 
                     AND fldusercode = @USERCODE)
```

The query's where clause doesn't return a single record, either add more parts to your where clause so it returns a single record, use an aggregate unction flddivisioncode, or fix the data you're querying so that those results are unique rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT TOP 1 flddivisioncode` 
       FROM sm.tblnataccuserdivisionmap WHERE 
           flddivisioncode=d.flddivisioncode
           AND fldentitycode = @ENTITYCODE
           AND fldusercode =@USERCODE)AS fldmapstatus
           FROM sm.tbldivisiondetails d
           INNER JOIN sm.tblnataccdivisionmapping m ON m.flddivisioncode=d.flddivisioncode
           AND fldcompanyentitycode =@ENTITYCODE
```