# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql

I need to know where is the problem with below stored procedure..it will return error of "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_APP_FP_Complete_Details]
    @FinishProductId int
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 
    userID,
    productTariffCode,
    tariffDesc,
    finishProductID,
    productDesc,
    tariffOfMeasurement,
    importCountry,
    productionCapacity,
    brandProduct,
    Manufacturerbrn,
    Manufacturername,
    Manfactoryaddress,
    Manfactorypostcode,
    Manfactorycity, 
    Manfactorystate

    (select [FileName] from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm_Attachment] where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId and FileType='3' ) FileName3,
    (select [FileName] from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm_Attachment] where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId and FileType='4' ) FileName4,
    (select [FileName] from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm_Attachment] where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId and FileType='5' ) FileName5,
    (select [FileName] from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm_Attachment] where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId and FileType='6' ) FileName6,
    (select [FileName] from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm_Attachment] where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId and FileType='7' ) FileName7,
    (select finishProductID from [dbo].APP_Raw_Material where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId ) FinishProductIDRM


    from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm]
    where  finishProductID=@FinishProductId and IsDeleted = 0    

END
```

Comment: yes, add top 1 in your select sub queries or limit 1

Comment: try to execute one of your subquery, maybe one of your subquery have more than one result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Comment: solve the query problem with adding Top 1 in sub queries. thanks for the suggestion @excaliburCayote

Comment: but be careful on the conditions, might affect the behavior of the query

Comment: Scalar functions can cause horrible performance issues -- and this looks like just one of those SQLs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearly using SQL Server syntax, so use `TOP 1`:

```
   (select  TOP 1 [FileName] from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm_Attachment] where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId and FileType='3' ) FileName3,
    (select TOP 1 [FileName] from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm_Attachment] where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId and FileType='4' ) FileName4,
    (select TOP 1 [FileName] from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm_Attachment] where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId and FileType='5' ) FileName5,
    (select TOP 1 [FileName] from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm_Attachment] where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId and FileType='6' ) FileName6,
    (select TOP 1 [FileName] from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm_Attachment] where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId and FileType='7' ) FileName7,
    (select TOP 1 finishProductID from [dbo].APP_Raw_Material where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId ) FinishProductIDRM
```

By the way, you can do the first 7 of these in the `from` clause.  This may be more efficient:

```
from [dbo].[APP_FinishProductCompleteForm] cf left join
     (select finishProductID,
             max(case when FileType = 1 then FileName end) as FileName1,
             max(case when FileType = 2 then FileName end) as FileName2,
             max(case when FileType = 3 then FileName end) as FileName3,
             max(case when FileType = 4 then FileName end) as FileName4,
             max(case when FileType = 5 then FileName end) as FileName5,
             max(case when FileType = 6 then FileName end) as FileName6,
             max(case when FileType = 7 then FileName end) as FileName7
      from dbo.APP_FinishProductCompleteForm_Attachment
      where finishProductID] = @FinishProductId
      group by finishProductID
     ) fp
     on fp.finishProductID = cf.finishProductID
```

In addition, your last subquery:

```
(select finishProductID
 from [dbo].APP_Raw_Material
 where [finishProductID]=@FinishProductId
) as FinishProductIDRM
```

may be the one causing a problem and it is a bit misleading.  How about using `exists` instead?

```
(case when exists (select 1
                   from APP_Raw_Material
                   where finishProductID = @FinishProductId
                  )
      then @FinishProductId
 end) as FinishProductIDRM
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon :) this helps me a lot :D