# Subquery returned more than 1 value. (Insert within a while loop)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

```
DECLARE @int int
DECLARE @saveamount int
DECLARE @savedate datetime
SET @int=1
SET @saveamount=400
SET @savedate= '20160101 13:00:00.00'
WHILE @int<=357
BEGIN
INSERT INTO watersave (reservoirid, amount, savedate)
             VALUES   (1,@saveamount,@savedate)


SET @int=@int+1
SET @saveamount=@saveamount+(SELECT ROUND((6 - 12 * RAND()), 0))
SET @savedate=@savedate+1
END
```

Trying to insert for test purposes but stacked with the subquery returned more than 1 value error on line 9.

Any idea? 
Regards

Comment: Is it this query that returns more than one value? SELECT ROUND((6 - 12 * RAND()), 0)

Comment: As seagulledge indicated, problem was because of trigger. I needed to update subquery in the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there does not appear to be any sub-queries in your SQL, check to see if there are any triggers on the [watersave] table.

reference:
[SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)