# how to select one column value using sub query in sql?

Tags: sql-server

when i run this query it will shown error

```
select Title,ParentTitle,(select   t.Title+'_'+t.ParentTitle   from CTE t join CTE s on t.Title=s.Title where t.visible=0 or t.visible=1 )as show  from CTE
```

when i the above query it will shown below result
result

```
 Title  ParentTitle show
    p1  Home    p1_Home
    p1.1    p1  p1_Home
    p1.1.1  p1.1    p1_Home
    p2  Home    p1_Home
    p2.1    p2  p1_Home
    p2.2    p2  p1_Home
    p2.3    p2.2    p1_Home
    P3  Home    p1_Home
    p3.1    p3  p1_Home
    P3.1.1  p3.1    p1_Home
```

Expected
result

```
Title   ParentTitle show
p1  Home    p1_Home
p1.1    p1  p1.1_p1
p1.1.1  p1.1    p1.1.1_p.11
p2  Home    p2_Home
p2.1    p2  p2.1_p2
p2.2    p2  p2.2_p2
p2.3    p2.2    p2.3_p2.2
P3  Home    p3_Home
p3.1    p3  p3.1_p3
P3.1.1  p3.1    p3.1.1_p3.1
```

Error message

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

how to solve this..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Comment: Can you please provide data of that table ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you can do something like:

```
select Title,ParentTitle,(select top 1 visible from CTE )as show  from CTE
```

or

```
select Title,ParentTitle,(select max(visible) from CTE )as show  from CTE
```

or whatever aggregation function you desire. This is what aggregation functions are doing, they aggregate the results and return one value.

Answer (score 0):

You need a WHERE clause in the sub-query to guarantee it returns a scalar value.

```
select Title,ParentTitle,(select visible from CTE WHERE Title = ????)as show  from CTE
```

You need to WHERE Title = ???? something logical based on your case instead of `WHERE Title = ????`

Comment: select Title,ParentTitle,(select visible from CTE where visible=0 )as show  from CTE i tried this..also error same...@FlICKER

Comment: Adding a condition won't necessarily fetch 1 row.

Comment: you need to change ti to return only 1 single row. if there are more than ONE row in CTE with visible=0, then still you get error. if none of the answers fix your problem. please provide more detail.

Comment: @sagi. is right, however having top 1, also is not a correct solution necessarily. pleae provide more detail about your question