# SQL Server error "SQL Server Sub query returned more than 1 value"

Tags: sql-server-2012, subquery, syntax-error

```
<!-- if version -->
```

query to change the recovery models and setup auto growth to 50 MB

```
USE MASTER   
GO    
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  
SET ARITHABORT ON  
GO
```

Took all the DB's except system databases.

```
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR(255),@LogicalFileName NVARCHAR(255),@DBRecoveryDesc Varchar(200), @isql varchar(2000)

DECLARE DatabaseList CURSOR   
FOR   
SELECT name,recovery_model_desc  
FROM sys.databases  
WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE'  
AND is_read_only = 0  
and database_id>4  
ORDER BY name
```

facing error near below subquery

```
OPEN DatabaseList  
FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseList INTO @DBName,@DBRecoveryDesc  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0     
BEGIN   
SET @LogicalFileName=(SELECT name FROM sys.master_files AS mf WHERE DB_NAME(database_id)=@DBName and type_desc='log' ) 

If @DBRecoveryDesc='Full'  
Begin  
select @isql = 'Use ['+@DBName+'] 
ALTER DATABASE ['+@DBName+'] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
ALTER DATABASE ['+@DBName+'] MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'''+@LogicalFileName+''', FILEGROWTH = 50)'
```

Script will give output script

    --exec(@isql) 
    print(@isql)
    END

```
If @DBRecoveryDesc='Simple'  
Begin   
select @isql = 'Use ['+@DBName+'] 
ALTER DATABASE ['+@DBName+'] MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'''+@LogicalFileName+''', FILEGROWTH = 50)' 

--exec(@isql)
print(@isql)
END
FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseList INTO @DBName,@DBRecoveryDesc
END  
CLOSE DatabaseList  
DEALLOCATE DatabaseList
```

Please help me to change the sub query details

Comment: you might want to elaborate on your question

Comment: Hi,

i have created one script for changing recovery model and setup auto growth to 50MB

but receiving subquery error while executing

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

please let me know is there any way we can SET @logicalfilename other than existed

Comment: It would be useful to show us the declaration of `@LogicalFileName` to confirm its type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your subquery:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.master_files AS mf 
WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = @DBName
AND type_desc = 'log'
```

returns more than one record (because the database named by `@DBName` has multiple log files) and therefore you cannot set `@LogicalFileName` to the result of this subquery - I presume that `@LogicalFileName` is a string type like `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`.

You either need to change your subquery so that it only ever returns a single value, or change the type of the `@LogicalFileName` variable so that is can handle multiple results (for example by declaring it as type `TABLE`).

Comment: Hi, I am unable paste my script . Is there any way we can change the script here .

Comment: Hi, I am unable paste my script . Is there any way we can change the script here @LogicalFileName is Nvarchar in my query.

Comment: What do you mean? You should be able to edit your own question if you want to add detail to it.

Comment: Hi, script added , Please help me to change the subquery

Comment: I'm not sure what you want us to do for you - the issue is that you have at least one database with multiple log files and so your subquery is returning multiple records which you then try to assign to a variable which cannot handle multiple values. You need to decide how you want to handle this, SO is not a free code writing service. If you have a specific question relating to a problem you're having in doing this, you should post it accordingly.

Comment: If you need to run your dynamic SQL for each file, then you probably need another cursor nested within your main cursor, to iterate through each file returned by your subquery - try doing that and post a new question if you have specific problems with this - don't just ask someone else to write it for you.