# Subquery returned more than 1 value not permitted when subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting that title error when I am doing select rows in the view of sql server.

here is my code

```
CREATE VIEW vw_cashbook AS
SELECT cashbooktranno, 
       cashbookdate, 
       cashbookrefaccname, 
       cashbookgroupname, 
       cashbookaccname, 
       cashbookdescription, 
       cashbookreceipt, 
       cashbookpayment,
       (select sum(cashbook.cashbookreceipt) - sum(cashbook.cashbookpayment) from tbl_cashbook) as totalpayment,
       company.companyname
FROM tbl_cashbook cashbook 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_companyregistration company 
               ON cashbook.branchid = company.companyid
group by cashbooktranno, cashbookdate, cashbookrefaccname, cashbookgroupname, cashbookaccname, 
cashbookdescription, cashbookreceipt, cashbookpayment, company.companyname
```

Now, this code is for to create the view from the table.
This code is very perfect and hence as per the code my view also created.
Now, the problem is that when I am select the rows from the created view or edit the view at that time it shows the error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Here is my select query for the view

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [cashbooktranno]
      ,[cashbookdate]
      ,[cashbookrefaccname]
      ,[cashbookgroupname]
      ,[cashbookaccname]
      ,[cashbookdescription]
      ,[cashbookreceipt]
      ,[cashbookpayment]
      ,[totalpayment]
      ,[companyname]
  FROM [AutoFinanceSoftware].[dbo].[vw_cashbook]
```

So is there any problem in my query or is there any other problem.

Comment: Can you show us the query you are using to select from this view please?

Comment: Did you get that error when you created the view?

Comment: @MartinBrown I have updated the select query in my question please review it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen no. I didnt get any error when I created the view.

Comment: What happens if you execute only the SELECT-part of the view creation, does it fail then too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for subquery. Use:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_cashbook AS
SELECT cashbooktranno, 
       cashbookdate, 
       cashbookrefaccname, 
       cashbookgroupname, 
       cashbookaccname, 
       cashbookdescription, 
       cashbookreceipt, 
       cashbookpayment,
       sum(cashbook.cashbookreceipt) - sum(cashbook.cashbookpayment) as totalpayment,
       company.companyname
FROM tbl_cashbook cashbook 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_companyregistration company 
               ON cashbook.branchid = company.companyid
group by cashbooktranno, cashbookdate, cashbookrefaccname, cashbookgroupname, cashbookaccname, 
cashbookdescription, cashbookreceipt, cashbookpayment, company.companyname;
```

Or even (if both columns are `NOT NULL`):

```
CREATE VIEW vw_cashbook AS
SELECT cashbooktranno, 
       cashbookdate, 
       cashbookrefaccname, 
       cashbookgroupname, 
       cashbookaccname, 
       cashbookdescription, 
       cashbookreceipt, 
       cashbookpayment,
       sum(cashbook.cashbookreceipt - cashbook.cashbookpayment) as totalpayment,
       company.companyname
FROM tbl_cashbook cashbook 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_companyregistration company 
               ON cashbook.branchid = company.companyid
group by cashbooktranno, cashbookdate, cashbookrefaccname, cashbookgroupname, cashbookaccname, 
cashbookdescription, cashbookreceipt, cashbookpayment, company.companyname
```