# SQL server 2016, subquery returned more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL server 2016, subquery returned more than one value.

I run the following query:

```
Select word,
       tabl2.nowdatetime,
       tabl2.MAX_COUNT_ID,
       tabl2.MIN_COUNT_ID,
       tabl2.[border(%)],
       tabl2.id
From   (
           Select word,
                  tabl.nowdatetime,
                  tabl.id,
                  Cast(tabl.MAX_COUNT_ID As Float) As MAX_COUNT_ID,
                  Cast(tabl.MIN_COUNT_ID As Float) As MIN_COUNT_ID,
                  ((((Cast(tabl.MAX_COUNT_ID As Float)) - (Cast(tabl.MIN_COUNT_ID As Float))) / (Cast(tabl.MIN_COUNT_ID As Float))) * 100) As 'border(%)'
           From   (
                      Select Distinct word,
                             (
                                 Select Max(nowdatetime)
                                 From   Presign_Problem
                                 Where  nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                             ) As nowdatetime,
                             (
                                 Select   Min(count_id)
                                 From     Presign_Problem pp2
                                 Where    pp1.word = pp2.word
                                          And nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                                 Group By word
                             ) As MIN_COUNT_ID,
                             (
                                 Select   Max(count_id)
                                 From     Presign_Problem pp2
                                 Where    pp1.word = pp2.word
                                          And nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                                 Group By word
                             ) As MAX_COUNT_ID,
                             (
                                 Select id
                                 From   Presign_Problem pp2
                                 Where  pp1.word = pp2.word
                                        And nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                                        And count_id = (
                                                           Select Max(count_id)
                                                           From   Presign_Problem pp3
                                                           Where  pp1.word = pp3.word
                                                                  And nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                                                       )
                             ) As id
                      From   Presign_Problem pp1
                      Where  nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                  ) tabl
           Where  tabl.id Is Not Null
       ) tabl2;
```

I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   Error in line below:
>   ,(select id from Presign_Problem pp2 where pp1.word=pp2.word and nowdatetime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -4, GETDATE()) and count_id = (SELECT MAX(count_id) FROM Presign_Problem pp3 where pp1.word=pp3.word and nowdatetime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -4, GETDATE()))  ) as id

Previously, the query did not display an error.

Below is an example of the data in the table:

```
word count_word count_id nowdatetime id 

computer 73 61 22.08.2017 15:24 ID23679381,ID48525000,ID23597299

computer 74 62 22.08.2017 14:24 ID23682019,ID23499955,ID23534359

computer 80 70 22.08.2017 12:24 ID23629307,ID48529530,ID23612836
```

Any ideas? How can i fix it?

Comment: Well, what is the question? Have you verified the data to ensure the query **shouldn't** return more than one row? Specifically, have you checked that the `Presign_Problem` table only have 1 row for the id you're looking for?

Comment: Almost all of your subqueries are using `GROUP BY` with aggregates - this will return multiple values... one for each grouping... and the other subquery is written in a way that multiple values can be pulled...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Comment: Except in your example table, all of the `count_id` values are distinct. Is that really true in your real data? More especially, what if there are multiple rows with the highest `count_id` value?

Comment: @Siyual - all of the queries using aggregates are grouping on the same column on which they're correlated with the outer query so, whilst in general your point applies, here there *should* only be a single result for each row of the outer query.

Comment: Correlated subqueries are almost always a poor idea. Casting ID numbers to float is a horrible choice. Float is not an exact data type and will change some of those ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Use `Aggregate` function Or `TOP` clause while selecting the ID.

I have used `TOP` clause here.

```
Select word,
       tabl2.nowdatetime,
       tabl2.MAX_COUNT_ID,
       tabl2.MIN_COUNT_ID,
       tabl2.[border(%)],
       tabl2.id
From   (
           Select word,
                  tabl.nowdatetime,
                  tabl.id,
                  Cast(tabl.MAX_COUNT_ID As Float) As MAX_COUNT_ID,
                  Cast(tabl.MIN_COUNT_ID As Float) As MIN_COUNT_ID,
                  ((((Cast(tabl.MAX_COUNT_ID As Float)) - (Cast(tabl.MIN_COUNT_ID As Float))) / (Cast(tabl.MIN_COUNT_ID As Float))) * 100) As 'border(%)'
           From   (
                      Select Distinct word,
                             (
                                 Select Max(nowdatetime)
                                 From   Presign_Problem
                                 Where  nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                             ) As nowdatetime,
                             (
                                 Select   Min(count_id)
                                 From     Presign_Problem pp2
                                 Where    pp1.word = pp2.word
                                          And nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                                 Group By word
                             ) As MIN_COUNT_ID,
                             (
                                 Select   Max(count_id)
                                 From     Presign_Problem pp2
                                 Where    pp1.word = pp2.word
                                          And nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                                 Group By word
                             ) As MAX_COUNT_ID,
                             (
                                 Select TOP 1 id
                                 From   Presign_Problem pp2
                                 Where  pp1.word = pp2.word
                                        And nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                                        And count_id = (
                                                           Select Max(count_id)
                                                           From   Presign_Problem pp3
                                                           Where  pp1.word = pp3.word
                                                                  And nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                                                       )
                             ) As id
                      From   Presign_Problem pp1
                      Where  nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
                  ) tabl
           Where  tabl.id Is Not Null
       ) tabl2;
```

Comment: This will fix the error, but without knowing the underlying data there's no guarantee that this will select the correct value for `id`.

Comment: @squillman That's what i have updated it in my answer. Based on the requirement he has to use Aggregate function or TOP clause.

Comment: Not necessarily.  It could just be a data issue in which case neither would be appropriate.

Comment: At any cost, user has to return one row in that query. Event it could be data issue, it wont provide wrong result.

Comment: Adding top 1 blindly is a poor idea. If there are two valid values, top one will exclude data you should see. Rewriting the query to remove correlated subqueries is a better choice in those cases.

Comment: @VigneshKumar - the correct result may be that there should be multiple output *rows* here - and so the subquery should become an `apply`/`join` instead.

Comment: @HLGEM Yeah definitely will rewrite it, if user provide the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

As it states in the error, this subquery:

```
Select id
From   Presign_Problem pp2
Where  pp1.word = pp2.word
    And nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
    And count_id = (
                       Select Max(count_id)
                       From   Presign_Problem pp3
                       Where  pp1.word = pp3.word
                              And nowdatetime >= DateAdd(Hour, -4, GetDate())
```

is returning multiple records which is not allowed in this context.  You want a single value for `id` here, but SQL Server doesn't know to pick the right one from the multiple values it found.  You need to either fix your data (such that `id` has only unique values for example) or change this query so that only 1 record is returned and you get a distinct value for id (adding DISTINCT to the Select, using an aggregate, etc).

Without knowing what the data is we can't tell you which one is the most appropriate option for you.