# SQL This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= o or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have faced the issue

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

while run the following query,

```
Select B.WhsCode 
     , A.DocNum 
     , A.NumAtCard 
     , Convert(Varchar(10), A.DocDate, 105) as 'DocDate'
     , A.CardCode 
     , A.CardName 
     , A.Address 
     , D.U_Brand as 'Brand' 
     , D.U_GProp as 'Product' 
     , D.U_GSem as 'Segment' 
     , B.ItemCode 
     , B.Dscription 
     , Cast(B.Quantity as Int) as 'Quantity' 
     , (
         SELECT Z.DistNumber 
           FROM dbo.ITL1 AS X 
          INNER JOIN dbo.OITL AS Y ON X.LogEntry = Y.LogEntry
          INNER JOIN dbo.OSRN AS Z ON X.ItemCode = Z.ItemCode 
                     and X.SysNumber = Z.SysNumber 
          WHERE Y.DocType = 13 
                and Y.DocEntry = A.DocEntry 
                and Y.DocLine = B.LineNum 
       ) as 'IMEI No' 
     , Cast((B.LineTotal) / B.Quantity as Numeric(19,2)) as 'Without Tax Price' 
     , Cast((B.LineVat) / B.Quantity as Numeric(19,2)) as 'Tax Amount' 
     , Cast((B.LineTotal + B.LineVat) / B.Quantity as Numeric(19,2)) as 'Price' 
     , B.TaxCode 
  From OINV A 
 INNER JOIN INV1 B On A.DocEntry = B.DocEntry 
       and (B.WhsCode = 'HO01' OR 'HO01' = 'HO01') 
       and B.Quantity > 0 
       and A.DocDate >= '2017-8-10' 
       and A.DocDate <= '2017-8-25' 
 INNER JOIN OITM C On B.ItemCode = C.ItemCode 
 INNER JOIN OITB D On C.ItmsGrpCod = D.ItmsGrpCod
```

Comment: Do a join instead of that sub-query in the select list.

Comment: Or add `MIN/MAX` like `MAX(Z.DistNumber)` or double check what you actually want/do

Comment: You have your answer (from @dnoeth) but you need to stop and think about your goal. Your subquery returns multiple values; therefore it is logically flawed. Min/Max (or any other aggregate) will remove the error. But is that **really** what you want to do? Do you understand both your schema, your query, and your resultset?

Comment: You may want min, max, sum or another aggregate. Or you may want `TOP (1)`  Only you can know what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)