# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a following query to update available stock of product stock master by sales master. It shows error when the sales table has a same prd_code . I am using invoice no for a condition but it takes all the records from sales master.My INVOICE_NO condition is not working here.

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @MaxCounts INT = (select distinct Count(prd_code) from SALES_D_ORG where INVOICE_NO=@INVOICE_NO)
WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MaxCounts)
BEGIN
update prd_stock set AVAILABLE_STOCK=((select AVAILABLE_STOCK from prd_stock where PRD_CODE=
(Select PRD_CODE From 
( Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By AUTO_NO) As RowNum, * From SALES_D_ORG Where INVOICE_NO=@INVOICE_NO) t2
Where RowNum = @LoopCounter))-(select qty from SALES_D_ORG where PRD_CODE=
(Select PRD_CODE From 
( Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By AUTO_NO) As RowNum, * From SALES_D_ORG  Where INVOICE_NO=@INVOICE_NO) t2
Where RowNum = @LoopCounter))) where PRD_CODE=(Select PRD_CODE From 
( Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By AUTO_NO) As RowNum, * From SALES_D_ORG  Where INVOICE_NO=@INVOICE_NO) t2
Where RowNum = @LoopCounter)
SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1        
END
```

Comment: The subquery returns more than one value in a place in your query where this makes no sense.  The error message cannot be more clear than this.

Comment: Your subquery return more that 1 row so  if you need  only a row form subselect you should limit the resul otherwise you need more rows  insetad  od = you should use IN

Comment: Thanks Tim Biegeleisen and scaisEdge. I have modified my code as yours suggestion.Now my code works fine as i expected.This will look like as follows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
UPDATE PRD_STOCK SET    SOLD_STOCK = (SELECT sum(SALES_D_ORG.QTY) FROM   SALES_D_ORG WHERE  SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE = PRD_STOCK.PRD_CODE) 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE FROM   SALES_D_ORG  WHERE  SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE = PRD_STOCK.PRD_CODE and SALES_D_ORG.INVOICE_NO=1)
END

BEGIN
update PRD_STOCK set AVAILABLE_STOCK=BATCH_STOCK-SOLD_STOCK 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE FROM   SALES_D_ORG WHERE  SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE = PRD_STOCK.PRD_CODE and SALES_D_ORG.INVOICE_NO=1)
END
```

Comment: I modified my code like this.it working as my expectation.But, i don't know about this whether it is a correct way to update specific columns of specific rows in a table from another table's specific rows. Please, guide me i am new to programming.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've updated your answer in another post so my response it related to that update.  I would start off by arranging statements on different lines with approriate spacing so it's readable to other people. Having everything on one line makes the code difficult to debug.

For example:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE PRD_STOCK 
   SET SOLD_STOCK = (SELECT sum(SALES_D_ORG.QTY) 
                       FROM SALES_D_ORG 
                      WHERE  SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE = PRD_STOCK.PRD_CODE) 
 WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE 
                  FROM SALES_D_ORG  
                 WHERE SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE = PRD_STOCK.PRD_CODE 
                   and SALES_D_ORG.INVOICE_NO = 1)
END

BEGIN
update PRD_STOCK 
   set AVAILABLE_STOCK = BATCH_STOCK-SOLD_STOCK 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE 
                 FROM SALES_D_ORG 
                WHERE  SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE = PRD_STOCK.PRD_CODE 
                  and SALES_D_ORG.INVOICE_NO = 1)
END
```

What I read from this is you're updating 2 fields. In the first update you update `SOLD_STOCK`.  If there exists a row `WHERE SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE = PRD_STOCK.PRD_CODE and SALES_D_ORG.INVOICE_NO = 1` then you update the field with the `sum(SALES_D_ORG.QTY) WHERE SALES_D_ORG.PRD_CODE = PRD_STOCK.PRD_CODE`.  I see nothing wrong with the code. It's up to you to decide if the logic behind the update is correct. Similarly, I see nothing wrong with the 2nd update. It is up to you, as the coder, to determine if your logic to apply the update is correct.

Comment: Thank you , your reply is very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't need any while loop or several sub queries. This script made same job.

```
UPDATE PS
SET 
    AVAILABLE_STOCK = AVAILABLE_STOCK - D.qty
FROM 
    prd_stock PS 
    INNER JOIN 
        ( SELECT PRD_CODE, SUM(qty) qty 
          FROM SALES_D_ORG 
          WHERE INVOICE_NO = @INVOICE_NO
          GROUP BY PRD_CODE ) D ON PS.PRD_CODE = D.PRD_CODE
```

Comment: Yes, i have modified my query.Now i am not using while loop.Thank you for your valuable answer.