# Inner join in Select Statement to create a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join

I have a `claimstable` like the following.

```
Time             Terminal_ID  Claims   Count
-------------------------------------------
2017-10-19 06:03:00     1      451        1
2017-10-19 06:04:00     1      452        2
2017-10-19 06:05:00     1      452.3      2
2017-10-19 06:06:00     1      458        2
2017-10-19 06:03:00     9      459        6 
2017-10-19 06:04:00     9      461.2      5
2017-10-19 06:05:00     9      462        2
2017-10-19 06:06:00     9      463        1
```

I select `time`, `claim` and create a new column `Claims_Change` from my table. After this, I insert it into a temporary table.

My expected output would be:

```
          Time       Terminal_ID  Claims   Count Claims_change
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    2017-10-19 06:03:00     1      451        1     Null
    2017-10-19 06:04:00     1      452        2     1
    2017-10-19 06:05:00     1      452.3      2     0.3
    2017-10-19 06:06:00     1      458        2     5.7
    2017-10-19 06:03:00     9      459        6     Null
    2017-10-19 06:04:00     9      461.2      5     2.2
    2017-10-19 06:05:00     9      462        2     0.8
    2017-10-19 06:06:00     9      463        1     1
```

This is my query:

```
select
    [Time], Terminal_ID, Claims, 
    convert(decimal(12, 3), y.[Claims] - (select t1.[Claims] 
                                          from claimstable t1 
                                          where t1.Terminal_ID = y.Terminal_ID 
                                            and t1.[Time] = (select max([Time])
                                                             from claimstable t2
                                                             where  t2.Terminal_ID = t1.Terminal_ID 
                                                               and t2.[Time] < y.[Time])
                    )) as Claims_change
into 
    #temptable
from 
    claimstable as y
```

When I tested this for 5000 rows, it works fine, however, when I test this with 100,000 rows, I get an error like this,

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 42
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I was reading some older [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s), the recommended answer was to use `inner join`.

Also, in my case, I don't know how to exactly write to get `Claims_change` variable using `inner join`.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: can you show the expected output as well?

Comment: You're trying to subtract a resultset from a number. If that resultset happens to return more than one value then SQL Server doesn't know what you actually want it to do. For example, what is 3 - (1, 4, 6)? If you intend to return multiple rows then you'll need to add additional information to your question specifying your exact requirements. If not then you need to figure out why you're getting multiple rows and what the business rules are to narrow that down to one row.

Comment: @TomH, you're correct, after your comment, I digged a little into the data and found that I had a duplicate record somehow. I found it and fixed it, thank you for the the awesome comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
select
    [Time], Terminal_ID, y.Claims, convert(decimal(12,3), y.[Claims]- t2.[Claims] ) as Claims_change
into 
    #temptable
from 
    claimstable as y
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 t1.[Claims] FROM claimstable t1 where
            t1.Terminal_ID = y.Terminal_ID AND y.[Time] > t1.[Time] ORDER BY [Time] DESC ) as  t2
```

Result:

```
Time                    Terminal_ID Claims       Claims_change
----------------------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
2017-10-19 06:03:00.000 1           451.00       NULL
2017-10-19 06:04:00.000 1           452.00       1.000
2017-10-19 06:05:00.000 1           452.30       0.300
2017-10-19 06:06:00.000 1           458.00       5.700
2017-10-19 06:03:00.000 9           459.00       NULL
2017-10-19 06:04:00.000 9           461.20       2.200
2017-10-19 06:05:00.000 9           462.00       0.800
2017-10-19 06:06:00.000 9           463.00       1.000
```

Comment: thank you for the effort, I will try this, and I am new to ` OUTER APPLY`. I'll try to read about it more!. However, as Tom H mentioned in comments above, he was right i think. I had a duplicate record that made the query to fail.

Answer (score 1):

If the version of SQL Server you are on supports `LAG`, use

```
select t.*,t.claims-lag(t.claims) over(partition by terminal_id order by time) as claims_change
from claimstable t
```

[`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) gets the value of a specified column from the previous row based on a specified ordering and partitioning. `LAG` for first row (in a partition) will be `NULL`. You can use the optional argument to specify a default value.

Comment: I am not aware of LAG. I am using Sql Server 2016 and I'll make sure, I'll read about it!