# SQL Server : setting variable using case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a script like:

```
DECLARE @OrderStatusIds VARCHAR(50);

SET @OrderStatusIds =
    (SELECT OrderStatusId FROM OrderStatus WHERE OrderStatusDescription = 
        CASE
            WHEN @OrderStatus  = 'Open' THEN 'Open'
            WHEN @OrderStatus  = 'Cancelled' THEN 'Cancelled'
            ELSE OrderStatusDescription -- get all order statuses
        END
    );

SELECT O.OrderNo, OS.OrderStatusDescription
FROM OrderHeader O
INNER JOIN OrderStatus OS ON O.OrderStatusId = OS.OrderStatusId
WHERE OH.OrderStatusId IN @OrderStatusIds
```

But I get an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I want to get a list of items and store it in that variable.

Thanks.

Comment: `OrderDescription - get all`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Comment: How are you expecting to store all of the results from your query in a single variable? Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: Think to change your variable to a table insteadif you are looking to get all the IDs, else you can use TOP 1

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  But remember, variables store single values, not tables of values.

Comment: I edited the code. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1):

You would use a table variable to store a *list* of order ids:

```
DECLARE @OrderIds TABLE (OrderId VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @OrderIds (OrderId)
    SELECT OrderId
    FROM Order
    WHERE ((OrderDescription = @OrderStatus) OR
           @OrderStatus NOT IN ('Open', 'Cancelled')
          );
```

Note that this replaces `CASE` with simpler boolean logic.  In general, you want to avoid `CASE` in `WHERE` clauses because they make it harder for the optimizer to optimize the query.

Comment: @Order variable is not defined.

Comment: @ZekiGumus . . . The `OP` changed the question.