# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: mysql, return, subquery, sqlclient

Since a couple of days ive had this error,

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Subquery
>   returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
>   follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression.

```
Line 16451:                dataTable.Clear();
Line 16452:            }
Line 16453:            int returnValue = this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);(here is the error)
Line 16454:            return returnValue;
Line 16455:        }
```

does anyone have any idea how to trace it or fix it, ive already went to the DB to check if they were duplicate values, but did not found.

Thanks for the help

Comment: no need to say thanks etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)