# Subquery returned more than 1 value error sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I'm trying make a query with a subquery in it where I want to sum on identification number. But it gives me the error: 
'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

I've already tried this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_Verblijfsobjecten_uitgeklapt]
AS
SELECT a.[Gemeentecode-AOB]
,a.[Code objecttypering-AOB]
,a.[Identificatie-AOB]
,a.[Gebruiksdoel]
,a.[Datum ontstaan-AOB]
,a.[Status code-AOB]
,a.[Buurtnaam]
,a.[Huisnummer]
,a.[Huisnummertoevoeging]
,a.[Postcode]
,a.[Identificatie-PND]
,a.[Geometrie]
,a.[Datum einde gebruik-AOB]
,a.[Einddatum-AOB]
,c.[DateValue]
,a.[Woonplaatsnaam]
,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(b.[Identificatie-AOB]))
  FROM [Clean.VBO] as b
  WHERE b.[Datum ontstaan-AOB] <= c.[DateValue] 
  AND (b.[Gebruiksdoel] IN ('1', '111', '11141', '11161', '121', '131', '141', '151', '161', '181'))
  AND (b.[Status code-AOB] <> 82)  
  AND (b.[Datum einde gebruik-AOB] = '2999-01-01' OR b.[Datum einde gebruik-AOB] > c.[DateValue])
  GROUP BY b.[Woonplaatsnaam]) AS AantalWoningenInDeTijd
FROM [Clean.VBO] as a 
INNER JOIN [Clean.Peilkalender] as c
ON a.[Datum ontstaan-AOB] <= c.[DateValue]
```

What I expect is that it counts the identification code based on "woonplaatsnaam" instead of a total number.

Comment: Your doing a group by so for every Woodplaatsnamm value you will get a count, so multiple rows

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When describing a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Minimal means adding minimal problem code to minimal working code. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: PS What did you learn googling that error message? This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. [ask] PS First you should post a question re an error message, because you are confused re the language or you have a typo/slip. If you then still have a problem with writing an appropriate program post another question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your subquery needs to be joined to the original table as follows:

```
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(b.[Identificatie-AOB]))
 FROM [Clean.VBO] as b
 WHERE a.[Woonplaatsnaam] = b.[Woonplaatsnaam] //added this line
 AND [Datum ontstaan-AOB] <= c.[DateValue] 
 AND (b.[Gebruiksdoel] IN ('1', '111', '11141', '11161', '121', '131', '141', '151', 
'161', '181'))
 AND (b.[Status code-AOB] <> 82)  
 AND (b.[Datum einde gebruik-AOB] = '2999-01-01' OR b.[Datum einde gebruik-AOB] > c. [DateValue])
 GROUP BY b.[Woonplaatsnaam]) AS AantalWoningenInDeTijd
```

This is called a `Correlated Subquery` and returns a `count` for each row in your original table through the `join`

Answer (score 3):

Your subquery is grouped by b.[Woon...incrediblylongnameinalanguagethatnobodyunderstands]

This will result in (possibly) multiple results depending on the column you are grouping by. This is not allowed in a subquery in the select or where part of your sql statement.

What you can do to retrieve your desired result is to place the subquery in the from part of your query. assign a handle to it and perform a proper join on the criterias you see fit. The resulting joined value can then be used in your select part of the query.

```
SELECT a.x, b.y, c.z 
   FROM A a 
   INNER JOIN B b
   INNER JOIN (<subselect>) c 
                              ON a.a = c.a
   WHERE ...
```

Comment: The language that nobody understands is Dutch :-)

Comment: @RobertKock: That wasnt the point i tried to bring across, but thanks.;)

Comment: I know. Just kiddin'

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very descriptive:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Let's suppose that you want to use a comparison operator which expects a single value. Example:

```
yourcolumn > (select yourcolumn2 from yourtable where yourcondition)
```

Now, let's suppose that your subquery will return two values: 5 and 7. Let's suppose further that in a case yourcolumn is 6. So, this would mean that you are interested to know whether 6 > (5, 7). But how should this comparison be executed? 6 > 5 is true, but 6 > 7 is false. So what should the result be? True? False? Null? Difficult to determine. There is no clearly defined way to evaluate that expression. So, for these operators you will need to have a single result for your subqueries. There are cases in which it is not required to have a unique result. Example:

```
yourcolumn in (select yourcolumn2 from yourtable where yourcondition)
```

In this case you are interested whether the value is inside a set.

Your actual query is attempting to insert into a table. The value of a field is determined by a subquery, but if the subquery has multiple results, then the result of the subquery is ambivalent and therefore fails to determine the value of the field, which is a show stopper.

So, according to your need you will need to cope with the situation. You can use your grouping query as a table and join it. Or you can avoid the group by. Or you can assure that you will have a single group for all the records to insert via where or having.

Answer (score 1):

remove group by from scaler subquery

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_Verblijfsobjecten_uitgeklapt]
AS
SELECT a.[Gemeentecode-AOB]
,a.[Code objecttypering-AOB]
,a.[Identificatie-AOB]
,a.[Gebruiksdoel]
,a.[Datum ontstaan-AOB]
,a.[Status code-AOB]
,a.[Buurtnaam]
,a.[Huisnummer]
,a.[Huisnummertoevoeging]
,a.[Postcode]
,a.[Identificatie-PND]
,a.[Geometrie]
,a.[Datum einde gebruik-AOB]
,a.[Einddatum-AOB]
,c.[DateValue]
,a.[Woonplaatsnaam]
,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(b.[Identificatie-AOB]))
  FROM [Clean.VBO] as b
  WHERE b.[Datum ontstaan-AOB] <= c.[DateValue] 
  AND (b.[Gebruiksdoel] IN ('1', '111', '11141', '11161', '121', '131', '141', '151', '161', '181'))
  AND (b.[Status code-AOB] <> 82)  
  AND (b.[Datum einde gebruik-AOB] = '2999-01-01' OR b.[Datum einde gebruik-AOB] > c.[DateValue])

  ) 
  AS AantalWoningenInDeTijd
FROM [Clean.VBO] as a 
INNER JOIN [Clean.Peilkalender] as c
ON a.[Datum ontstaan-AOB] <= c.[DateValue]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure I understood what you want but I guess you can obtain what you need by changing the subquery a little:

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(b.[Identificatie-AOB]))
  FROM [Clean.VBO] as b
  WHERE b.[Datum ontstaan-AOB] <= c.[DateValue] 
  AND (b.[Gebruiksdoel] IN ('1', '111', '11141', '11161', '121', '131', '141', '151', '161', '181'))
  AND (b.[Status code-AOB] <> 82)  
  AND (b.[Datum einde gebruik-AOB] = '2999-01-01' OR b.[Datum einde gebruik-AOB] > c.[DateValue])
  AND (b.[Woonplaatsnaam] = a.[Woonplaatsnaam]) AS AantalWoningenInDeTijd -- Extend the condition instead of grouping by
)
```

Comment: This was exactly the solution I was looking for! Thanks