# Subquery returned more than 1 value errors

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    CASE CR.claim_status 
       WHEN 'RC' 
          THEN (SELECT ins_clause_no 
                FROM tbl_rej_code_master RCM 
                WHERE CR.s_no IN (SELECT s_no 
                                  FROM claim_rejection_code_trans CRCT 
                                  WHERE CRCT.irrmp_sr_no = RCM.rej_srno)) 
    END 
FROM   
    tblclaimregistration CR 

SELECT 
    CASE CR.claim_status 
       WHEN 'RC' THEN (SELECT clause_no 
                       FROM claim_rejection_code_trans CRCT 
                       WHERE CR.s_no = CRCT.s_no) 
    END AS Clause_No 
FROM
    tblclaimregistration CR;
```

while running this code I am getting the error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Please help

Comment: The error message is clear, the subquery returns more than one row. What's not clear there?

Comment: With no `ORDER BY` @Sreenu131?

Comment: @Larnu with order by only ,i forget to mention thanks bro

Comment: As @Sami said, the error is very clear here. What are you expecting to happen when your subquery returns more than 1 row, with different values? If the subquery returns rows with the value `'RC'` and `'AB'` should the `CASE` expression still evaluate to true? Or are you actually expecting the subquery to only return 1 row? If that is the case, then it seems you need to include further criteria in the subquery's `WHERE`, or you don't understand your data correctly and it *should* return more than one row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)

Comment: I think what you really need here is to fix the logic of your query. It seems to be a bit left of center.

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery in case statement returns more than 1 value.

You must return just one value because this subquery executed per row of CR table.

You can used "TOP 1" in each subquery.

For example:

```
SELECT 
CASE CR.claim_status 
   WHEN 'RC' 
      THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ins_clause_no 
            FROM tbl_rej_code_master RCM 
            WHERE CR.s_no IN (SELECT s_no 
                              FROM claim_rejection_code_trans CRCT 
                              WHERE CRCT.irrmp_sr_no = RCM.rej_srno ORDER BY <Your Column>)) 
END 
FROM   
tblclaimregistration CR 

SELECT 
CASE CR.claim_status 
   WHEN 'RC' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 clause_no 
                   FROM claim_rejection_code_trans CRCT 
                   WHERE CR.s_no = CRCT.s_no ORDER BY <Your Column>) 
END AS Clause_No 
FROM
tblclaimregistration CR;
```

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` this will just return a random row, and that random row might well not be the row the OP is after.

Comment: Hi @Larnu
That's true. I forget to write order by. Thanks for your tip.