# Display date in the column depending on certain conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

While running the below code, I am getting the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows `=`, `!=`, `<`, `<=` , `>`, `>=` or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression

when I add the last bit of code (see after union)

```
(select top 1 convert(varchar,PaymentDate,103) from tblUTRDetail where CCN_No=CR.CCN_NO and CR.Claim_Status='Y' order by PaymentDate desc
union all
select top 1 convert(varchar,CreatedDate,103) from tblOpenCloseTrans where S_NO=CR.S_NO and OpenCloseType='C' and CR.Claim_Status='C' order by CreatedDate desc
union all
select top 1 convert(varchar,GENERATED_DATE,103) from tbldeficiencyletterTrans where S_NO=CR.S_NO and DEFICIENT_REPUDATION_FLAG='NC' and CR.Claim_Status='NC' order by GENERATED_DATE desc
union all
select top 1 convert(varchar,GENERATED_DATE,103) from tbldeficiencyletterTrans where S_NO=CR.S_NO and DEFICIENT_REPUDATION_FLAG='R' and CR.Claim_Status='RC' order by GENERATED_DATE desc
union 
(select GENERATED_DATE from  (Select s_no, convert (varchar,(GENERATED_DATE),103)as GENERATED_DATE ,row_number()
over(partition by s_no order by s_no asc )as rw from tblDeficiencyLetterTrans b
where DEFICIENT_REPUDATION_FLAG='NC' and s_no=CR.S_NO) T where rw=1)
) 
as SETTLEMENT_DATE,
```

Comment: at least post your full query. Although input and output data is also expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks like this:

```
SELECT *

,(select 1 union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 3
union (select 4)) as SETTLEMENT_DATE
FROM sys.tables
```

You are selecting some columns values and the for one of them you can return up to 4 values for one column `SETTLEMENT_DATE`.

So, you can have multiple values where one value is expected and this is what the error is saying to you. You have to options:

- if you want to see all values, just give a separated name to each column like this

  ```
  SELECT *

  ,select 1 as SETTLEMENT_DATE1
  ,
  select 2 as SETTLEMENT_DATE2
  ,
  select 3 as SETTLEMENT_DATE3
  ,
  select 3 as SETTLEMENT_DATE4
  ,
  (select 4) as SETTLEMENT_DATE5
  FROM sys.tables
  ```
- add more logic to return only one value each time from this sub-query

  ```
  (
      SELECT TOP 1 date
      FROM
      (

          (select top 1 convert(varchar,PaymentDate,103) from tblUTRDetail where CCN_No=CR.CCN_NO and CR.Claim_Status='Y' order by PaymentDate desc
          union all
          select top 1 convert(varchar,CreatedDate,103) from tblOpenCloseTrans where S_NO=CR.S_NO and OpenCloseType='C' and CR.Claim_Status='C' order by CreatedDate desc
          union all
          select top 1 convert(varchar,GENERATED_DATE,103) from tbldeficiencyletterTrans where S_NO=CR.S_NO and DEFICIENT_REPUDATION_FLAG='NC' and CR.Claim_Status='NC' order by GENERATED_DATE desc
          union all
          select top 1 convert(varchar,GENERATED_DATE,103) from tbldeficiencyletterTrans where S_NO=CR.S_NO and DEFICIENT_REPUDATION_FLAG='R' and CR.Claim_Status='RC' order by GENERATED_DATE desc
          union 
          (select GENERATED_DATE from  (Select s_no, convert (varchar,(GENERATED_DATE),103)as GENERATED_DATE ,row_number()
          over(partition by s_no order by s_no asc )as rw from tblDeficiencyLetterTrans b
          where DEFICIENT_REPUDATION_FLAG='NC' and s_no=CR.S_NO) T where rw=1)
          ) 
      )  DS (date)
      ORDER BY date
  )
  as SETTLEMENT_DATE,
  ```

Comment: i want the date in only one column as per the conditions in my query and not in different columns

Comment: i am selecting different dates (PaymentDate,CreatedDate,GENERATED_DATE)

Comment: so how do i select a particluar date in top 1

Comment: @GIRIJA The same way you did it in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629468/subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-errors).

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tempT (Material varchar(10),yyyyww  int,item_type  varchar(10),TPT int    )
-------------Insert---------------
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'Assembly'  , 7)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'Assembly'  , 6)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'Assembly'  , 7)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'Assembly'  , 7)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'FG'        , 2)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'FG'        , 2)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'FG'        , 1)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'TEST'      , 7)
insert into #tempT values('E123'    ,    201919 , 'TEST'      , 4)

------------Output-------------
select Material ,ceiling(((sum((MaxTPT)))/7.00)+1)MaxTPT  
 from(select Material,item_type,case when item_type='Assembly' then max(TPT)
when item_type='fg' then max(TPT)
when item_type='TEST' then max(TPT) end MaxTPT from #tempT
group by Material,item_type)a`enter code here`
group by Material
```

Comment: Kindly Ignore the answer