# Why 'Subquery returned more than 1 value'?

Tags: sql-server

I run the following query but I'm getting:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
UPDATE Maid 
SET Maid_Hours = (SELECT SUM(c.Duration_Hours) 
                  FROM Appointments
                  LEFT JOIN Duration c ON Duration_ID = Appointment_Duration 
                  WHERE WO_MaidName = 4
                    AND (IsDelete = 0 OR IsDelete = NULL)
                    AND DATEPART(m, Appointment_DateTime) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
                    AND DATEPART(yyyy, Appointment_DateTime) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
                  GROUP BY Appointment_Duration)
WHERE Maid_ID = 4
```

Comment: `GROUP BY Appointment_Duration` will give you one result per duration i.e. multiple rows... which doesn't work when you want to update a single value.

Comment: Please see the link below, the solution of your question. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s)