# Finding and using value within stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find a value and then use this within another statement within the same SQL stored procedure . However I am lost with the syntax (if this is even possible).

Below I have posted my code as this will be the easiest way to explain fully.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindRuidForUser
    @Email nvarchar (160),
    @RUId int,
    @DeskLocation nvarchar(160),
    @ExtraInformation nvarchar(160),
    @PrimaryWorkStation nvarchar(160),
    @Date datetime
AS
    SELECT RUId 
    FROM RegisteredUsers
    WHERE Email = @Email

RUId = @RUId

Then

    INSERT INTO diffrenttable (RUId, PrimaryWorkStation, DeskLocation, ExtraInformation, TimeCreated)
    VALUES (@RUId, @PrimaryWorkStation, @DeskLocation, @ExtraInformation, @TimeCreated)
```

I would first like to find the RUId and then I would like to insert this into a separate table along with the rest of the variables I will be using.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you !

Comment: You should be able to use `SELECT TOP 1 RUId FROM RegisteredUsers
WHERE Email = @Email` in place of `@RUId` in the `INSERT` statement. But you might want to add some check for if there actually is an `Email = @Email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the syntax. Note this is just a syntax how I have used created a variable of the name `@SomeNewRUID`. After creating the value has been assigned and used in the insert statement.

```
create procedure FindRuidForUser
@Email nvarchar (160),
@RUId int,
@DeskLocation nvarchar(160),
@ExtraInformation nvarchar(160),
@PrimaryWorkStation nvarchar(160),
@Date datetime
as
Begin
   declare @SomeNewRUID int
   select @SomeNewRUID = RUId from RegisteredUsers where Email = @Email

   INSERT into diffrenttable (RUId,PrimaryWorkStation,DeskLocation,ExtraInformation, 
  TimeCreated)
   values (@SomeNewVariable, @PrimaryWorkStation, @DeskLocation, @ExtraInformation, @TimeCreated)
End
```

Here is another example from the [reference](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/variables/) to know more how to use the variable in a SQL Server stored procedure.

```
CREATE  PROC uspGetProductList(
    @model_year SMALLINT
) AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @product_list VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @product_list = '';

    SELECT
        @product_list = @product_list + product_name 
                        + CHAR(10)
    FROM 
        production.products
    WHERE
        model_year = @model_year
    ORDER BY 
        product_name;

    PRINT @product_list;
END;
```

Note, Only one value should come from the select statement while assigning it into that variable otherwise, it will give the error like:

[SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s/3915182).

Answer (score 1):

A little adjustment in your stored proc:
In your

```
select top 1 @RUId = RUId from RegisteredUsers
where Email = @Email
```

I added a top in case you have more RUI returned for one Email.

```
create procedure FindRuidForUser

@Email nvarchar (160),
@RUId int,

@DeskLocation nvarchar(160),
@ExtraInformation nvarchar(160),
@PrimaryWorkStation nvarchar(160),
@Date datetime


as

select top 1 @RUId = RUId from RegisteredUsers
where Email = @Email



Then

INSERT into diffrenttable (RUId,PrimaryWorkStation,DeskLocation,ExtraInformation, TimeCreated)
values (@RUId, @PrimaryWorkStation, @DeskLocation, @ExtraInformation, @TimeCreated)
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you have this following code:

```
select RUId from RegisteredUsers
where Email = @Email

RUId = @RUId
```

You should be able to do the following instead:

```
select @RUId = RUId from RegisteredUsers
where Email = @Email
```

Alternatively, you could have written:

```
set @RUId = (select RUId from RegisteredUsers
where Email = @Email)
```

Your current line of code wouldn't work, because the select statement isn't assigning your request to anything.  Setting the parameter to what you're looking for should do the trick.

Comment: @SS_DBA, thanks for the catch.   Definite oversight on my end.