# Subquery returned more than 1 value with Iif conditions

Tags: sql-server, subquery

```
select *
from employee
where controllingoffice in (
    Iif(1=1, (select id from controllingoffice), (select id from controllingoffice where OwnerId=4))
)
```

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Note: Both subquery return more than 1 row

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653188/sql-server-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-s/3915182

Comment: Please get familiar on "how to ask a proper question" and provide some consumable example data. Anyways, you might want to try to modify the query as follows: `SELECT e.* FROM employee AS e INNER JOIN controllingoffice AS c ON c.id = e.controllingoffice AND c.id = CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN c.id ELSE 4 END`.

Comment: Isn't the second query a subset of the first one? Either way you can just use an `or` at the outermost level or a `union` of the two queries.

Comment: Wait, since 1 always equals 1, won't the IIF always return the first argument?  I don't get that code sample at all.

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear to you?

Comment: @hsn FYI if you want answers to your questions you need to interact with the people leaving comments.

Comment: Well my question is very simple, why  sub query return error when case/iif condition used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your query fails is because your subqueries return multiple values while the `iif()` function is expecting scalar results for its arguments. Because `iif()` is a function, it evaluates to a single value and not a set of rows. You can't use it to branch as you would in a procedural language so you can't make the execution of the subqueries conditional in that sense.

The subquery below allows you to express the driving condition once in one place. That can be handy if this uses dynamic SQL. I'm presuming that your `1 = 1` is a placeholder for that input. The switching condition determines whether all rows are returned or just the ones for the single `OwnerId`:

```
select *
from employee
where controllingoffice in (
    select id from controllingoffice where
    <switch condition> or OwnerId = 4
);
```

By the way the logic `X or (~X)Y` reduces to `X or Y`

An approximation to what you intended to happen would look something like this:

```
select *
from employee
where
    1 = 1 and controllingoffice in (
        select id from controllingoffice
    )
 or 0 = 1 and controllingoffice in (
        select id from controllingoffice where OwnerId = 4
    );
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct: As far as I understood the `1=1`merely represents a switch, so I guess the intention is `either return all employees of all controllingoffices OR (if other switch state) return only of a selected office (in this case 4)` - your example will return all employees of office 4 only... or am I missing something here? `or` doen't equal `xor`, right?

Comment: @Tyron78 as I noted at the end the `not X` part of the logic is redundant (as long as nulls are involved.) The rows for `OwnerId = 4` are *always* returned Sometimes they're just the only rows as when the switch is off.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if the condition is going to look like `@input = 1` or it it's just going to be inserted as dynamic sql.

Comment: Just replace * with Id in where condition, it worked Thanks a lot @shawnt00